# Find unique combinations based on two columns and calculate the mean

Tags: r, unique, dataframe

I have a problem in R, which I can't seem to solve.

I have the following dataframe:

[Image 1](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B_v_3frEDiceRkppWHhaOUM4LTA)

I would like to:

1. Find the unique combinations of the columns 'Species' and 'Effects'
2. Report the concentration belonging to this unique combination
3. If this unique combination is present more than one time, calculate the **mean** concentration

And would like to get the following dataframe:

[Image 2](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B_v_3frEDiced3dpZ1p0ZG1JWWs)

I have tried next script to get the unique combinations:

UniqueCombinations <- Data[!duplicated(Data[,1:2]),]

but don't know how to proceed from there.

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Tina

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you include your example data as reproducible R code rather than images? See http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/892313 for some tips on how to do so.

Comment: +1 for bringing new meaning to "show us your data"

Comment: -1 for bringing new meaning to "show us your data". Why not show us `head(Data)` or `dput(head(Data))` or even `str(Data)`?

Comment: Downvoted due to dead links.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following (Thanks Brandon Bertelsen for nice comment):

Creating your data:

```
foo = data.frame(Species=c(rep("A",4),"B",rep("C",3),"D","D"), 
                 Effect=c(rep("Reproduction",3), rep("Growth",2),
                          "Reproduction", rep("Mortality",2), rep("Growth",2)), 
                 Concentration=c(1.2,1.4,1.3,1.5,1.6,1.2,1.1,1,1.3,1.4))
```

Using great package `plyr` for a bit of magic :)

```
library(plyr)
ddply(foo, .(Species,Effect), function(x) mean(x[,"Concentration"]))
```

And this is a bit more complicated, but cleaner version (Thanks again to Brandon Bertelsen):

```
ddply(foo, .(Species,Effect), summarize, mean=mean(Concentration))
```

Comment: Cleaner: `ddply(foo,.(Species,Effect),...`

Comment: Cleaner-er: `...,.(Species, Effect), summarize, mean=mean(Concentration))`

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I would like to ask a question regarding this answer, but I can't fit it in this box, as i also want to ad R scripts and outputs. What is the best way to do so?
Should i start with a new question page?
Thanks,
Tina

Comment: @TinaVanRegenmortel You are welcome to post a new question. Write it in a way that it would be useful for the others and before posting your question, search a few to be sure your question is not already answered on StackOverflow

Answer (score 6):

Create some example data:

```
dat <- data.frame(Species = rep.int(LETTERS[1:4], c(4, 1, 3, 2)),
                  Effect = c(rep("Reproduction", 3), "Growth", "Growth",
                             "Reproduction", "Mortality", "Mortality",
                             "Growth", "Growth"),
                  Concentration = rnorm(10))
```

You can use the function `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(Concentration ~ Species + Effect, dat, mean)
```

Answer (score 5):

Just for fun before I call it a night.... Assuming your `data.frame` is called "dat", here are two more options:

1. A `data.table` solution.

   ```
   library(data.table)
   datDT <- data.table(dat, key="Species,Effect")
   datDT[, list(Concentration = mean(Concentration)), by = key(datDT)]
   #    Species       Effect Concentration
   # 1:       A       Growth          1.50
   # 2:       A Reproduction          1.30
   # 3:       B       Growth          1.60
   # 4:       C    Mortality          1.05
   # 5:       C Reproduction          1.20
   # 6:       D       Growth          1.35
   ```
2. An `sqldf` solution.

   ```
   library(sqldf)
   sqldf("select Species, Effect,
         avg(Concentration) `Concentration`
         from dat
         group by Species, Effect")
   #   Species       Effect Concentration
   # 1       A       Growth          1.50
   # 2       A Reproduction          1.30
   # 3       B       Growth          1.60
   # 4       C    Mortality          1.05
   # 5       C Reproduction          1.20
   # 6       D       Growth          1.35
   ```