# How to find number of unique ids corresponding to each date in a data drame

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, unique

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
      date         time              id            datetime    
1 2015-01-02 14:27:22.130 999000000007628 2015-01-02 14:27:22 
2 2015-01-02 14:41:27.720 989001002807730 2015-01-02 14:41:27 
3 2015-01-02 14:41:27.940 989001002807730 2015-01-02 14:41:27 
4 2015-01-02 14:41:28.140 989001002807730 2015-01-02 14:41:28 
5 2015-01-02 14:41:28.170 989001002807730 2015-01-02 14:41:28 
6 2015-01-02 14:41:28.350 989001002807730 2015-01-02 14:41:28
```

I need to find the number of unique "id"s for each "date" in that data frame.

I tried this:

```
sums<-data.frame(date=unique(data$date), numIDs=0)

for(i in unique(data$date)){
  sums[sums$date==i,]$numIDs<-length(unique(data[data$date==i,]$id))
}
```

and I got the following error:

```
 Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "numIDs", value = 0L) : 
   replacement has 1 row, data has 0
 In addition: Warning message:
 In `==.default`(data$date, i) :
   longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Any ideas?? Thank you!

Hopefully this helps!

```
data <- structure(list(date = structure(list(sec = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0), min = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    hour = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), mday = c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), mon = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), year = c(115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 
    115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L), wday = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), yday = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), isdst = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), zone = c("PST", "PST", "PST", "PST", "PST", 
    "PST", "PST", "PST", "PST", "PST"), gmtoff = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_)), .Names = c("sec", 
"min", "hour", "mday", "mon", "year", "wday", "yday", "isdst", 
"zone", "gmtoff"), class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt")), time = c("14:27:22.130", 
"14:41:27.720", "14:41:27.940", "14:41:28.140", "14:41:28.170", 
"14:41:28.350", "14:41:28.390", "14:41:28.520", "14:41:28.630", 
"14:41:28.740"), id = c("999000000007628", "989001002807730", 
"989001002807730", "989001002807730", "989001002807730", "989001002807730", 
"989001002807730", "989001002807730", "989001002807730", "989001002807730"
), datetime = structure(list(sec = c(22.13, 27.72, 27.94, 28.14, 
28.17, 28.35, 28.39, 28.52, 28.63, 28.74), min = c(27L, 41L, 
41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L), hour = c(14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L), mday = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), mon = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), year = c(115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 
115L, 115L, 115L), wday = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
     5L), yday = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), isdst = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), zone = c("PST", "PST", "PST", 
    "PST", "PST", "PST", "PST", "PST", "PST", "PST"), gmtoff =     c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_)), .Names = c("sec", 
    "min", "hour", "mday", "mon", "year", "wday", "yday", "isdst", 
    "zone", "gmtoff"), class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt")), site = c("Chivato", 
    "Chivato", "Chivato", "Chivato", "Chivato", "Chivato", "Chivato", 
    "Chivato", "Chivato", "Chivato")), .Names = c("date", "time", 
    "id", "datetime", "site"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `uniqueN` function from `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, uniqueN(id), by = date]
```

or (as per the comment of @Richard Scriven):

```
aggregate(id ~ date, df, function(x) length(unique(x)))
```

Comment: I tried:

                         setDT(data)[, uniqueN(id), by = date]

and got the error:

                Error in byval[[jj]] : subscript out of bounds

Comment: @Alexis It should work (and works on the example data you provided). Could you include data & code in the question with which that error can be reproduced?

Comment: here is my error:

     setDT(Chivato)[, uniqueN(id), by = date]
Error in byval[[jj]] : subscript out of bounds

Comment: @Alexis  Please post `dput(head(data))` **inside** your question.

Comment: @Alexis  You just posted `head(data)` in comments. Please post `dput(head(data, n = 10))`.

Comment: @Pascal I posted it into the original question with n=2 because even at n=2 it was too long for a comment

Comment: @Alexis  `n=2` is almost useless. Please uses at least `n=10`. And it is posted in the **question**, so it is fine.

Comment: @Alexis The formatting of the  `date` column is causing the trouble. Could you try: `setDT(data)[, uniqueN(id), by = as.Date(date)]`?

Comment: @Alexis I did nothing. For future question, please provide a `dput()` or `dput(head())`, to speed up the process.

Comment: @Pascal I will. Thank you! Good to know!

Answer (score 2):

Or we could use `n_distinct` from `library(dplyr)`

```
library(dplyr) 
df %>%
   group_by(date) %>%
   summarise(id=n_distinct(id))
```

Comment: @Pascal  If the OP's 'data' is `POSIXlt` class, which the `dplyr` wont' allow, it is better to convert it outside the `%>%` to 'Date' class, i.e. `data$date <- as.Date(date)` and it should work.

Comment: Good to know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is in response to this post: [group by and then count unique observations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36039309/5220858) which was marked as duplicate as I was writing this draft. This is not in response to the question for the duplicate basis here:  [How to find number of unique ids corresponding to each date in a data drame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33251264/5220858) which asks about finding unique ID's.  I'm not sure the second post actually answers the OP's question which is,

> "I want to create a table with the number of unique `id` for each
>   combination of `group1` and `group2`."

The keyword here is 'combination'. The interpretation is each `id` has a particular value for `group1` and a particular value for `group2` so that the set of data of interest is the particular set of values `c(id, group1, group2)`.

Here is the data.frame the OP provided:

```
df1 <- data.frame(id=sample(letters, 10000, replace = T),
group1=sample(1:2, 10000, replace = T),
group2=sample(100:101, 10000, replace = T))
```

Using `data.table` inspired by this post -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/13017723/5220858:

```
>library(data.table)
>DT <- data.table(df1)
>DT[, .N, by = .(group1, group2)]

   group1 group2    N
1:      1    100 2493
2:      1    101 2455
3:      2    100 2559
4:      2    101 2493
```

N is the count for the `id` that has a particular `group1` value and a particular `group2` value. Expanding to include the `id` also returns a table of 104 unique `id`, `group1`, `group2` combinations.

```
>DT[, .N, by = .(id, group1, group2)]

     id group1 group2   N
  1:  t      1    100 107
  2:  g      1    101  85
  3:  l      1    101  98
  4:  a      1    100  83
  5:  j      1    101  98
 ---                     
100:  p      1    101  96
101:  r      2    101  91
102:  y      1    101 104
103:  g      1    100  83
104:  r      2    100  77
```