# group by and then count unique observations

Tags: r, dplyr

My data looks something like this:

```
set.seed(3162016)
df1 <- data.frame(id=sample(letters, 10000, replace = T), 
                  group1=sample(1:2, 10000, replace = T), 
                  group2=sample(100:101, 10000, replace = T))
```

I want to create a table with the number of unique `id` for each combination of `group1`and `group2`.

I'm able to the the count with this code:

```
df1 %>% group_by(group1, group2) %>% summarise(n=n())
```

or I can get the unique count that I want for a given group with this

```
df1 %>% filter(group1 == 1, group2 == 100) %>% distinct() %>% nrow()
```

Alas, I'm not sure how to create the table that I want. I guess I could create my own function, but i'm hopping there is an easier way.

Comment: Maybe `df1 %>% group_by(group1, group2) %>% summarise(n=length(unique(id)))`?

Comment: That is much more obvious than what I expected. I was way overthinking this... Thanks!

Comment: `n_distinct` is the function you want, eh?

Comment: shorthand for `length(unique(id))` is `n_distinct(id)`.